# Using hidden field as a row index in GridView (its DataSource is a DataTable ) 

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `GridView1` declared as:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLines="None" DataKeyNames="Case_ID">
  <Columns>
      <asp:TemplateField>
           <ItemTemplate><asp:CheckBox ID="cb" runat="server" /></ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
      <asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="No.">
           <ItemTemplate><%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %></ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
      <asp:BoundField  HeaderText="Case Title"  DataField="caseTitle"/>
      <asp:BoundField  HeaderText="Age" DataField="age" />
      <asp:BoundField  HeaderText="Gender"  DataField="gender"/>
      <asp:BoundField  HeaderText="Treated By" DataField="owner"/>
      <asp:BoundField  HeaderText="Added Date"  DataField="sDate"/>
      <asp:BoundField  HeaderText=""  DataField="Case_ID" Visible="false"/>
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

and this is the `DataTable` I'm using as a `DataSource` for it

```
DataTable aTable = new DataTable();

aTable.Columns.Add("caseTitle", typeof(string));
aTable.Columns.Add("age", typeof(string));
aTable.Columns.Add("gender", typeof(string));
aTable.Columns.Add("owner", typeof(string));
aTable.Columns.Add("sDate", typeof(string));
aTable.Columns.Add("Case_ID", typeof(int));
```

I want to use `Case_ID` as an index for the `GridView`, so I can delete a record from database when I check its check box in the `GridView`.

---

Sorry if my question was not that clear ..

I don't know where the problem exactly is, I hope you can help me.

here is the scenario:

- `GridView` displays cases information from database
- User can check check-boxes and then click [Delete] button, this action should delete the records from database;

for that reason I need to have the primary key (`Case_ID`) in my GridView but I don't need it to be visible.

When I execute this code in [Delete] button:

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
{
    CheckBox c = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("cb");

    if (c.Checked)
    {
        int rowIndex = GridView1.SelectedIndex;
        string id = GridView1.DataKeys[rowIndex].Value.ToString();
        ds.DeleteCommand = " delete from Cases where Case_ID=" + id + "";
        ds.Delete();
    } 
}
```

nothing is deleted! I don't know why!

It is working when the `DataDource` of the `GridView` is an `SqlDataSource`, but with the `DataTable` it is not.

I hope its clear now.

***Edit:***
*when using `breakpoints` I found that `c` is always `null` even when I'm checking some records; so the problem is its not detecting the change in the `checkbox` what can I do to make it detected? *

Comment: yes please , I want to use Case_ID as an index for the GridView , so I can delete a record from database when I checked its check box in the GridView

Comment: So, do u want to know how to get the `Case_Id` of the row upon checkbox `oncheckchanged` or smth?

Comment: I edited the post , please take a look , Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use your DataKey on RowCommand (Delete Command) like this:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Delete") {
        int Case_ID = ((GridView)sender).DataKeys[e.CommandArgument].Values[0].ToString();
        // TODO, your delete routine
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your replay
but I need the checked records to be deleted using [Delete] button. do you have any idea?

Comment: Use my example with a command button on your GV to delete a single record.

Comment: it is not working either ,, this error message appears "Non-invocable member 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.DataKeys' cannot be used like a method."

Comment: it doesn't work .. I found that the checkbox is always null that's why it is not deleted, but how can I make it detect the checking?

Answer (score 0):

You are using

```
int rowIndex = GridView1.SelectedIndex;
```

in your loop.  For each row, you are going to get the same `SelectedIndex`. Shouldn't you be indexing off of the current `row` that you are enumerating over?  Also, use the debugger to step thru the code, examing variables.  The issue may jump out at you.  If your using transactions, make sure it is committing.

You could try something like:

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)  
{  
    CheckBox c = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("cb");  

    if (c.Checked)  
    {  
        string id = row["Case_ID"].ToString();  
        ds.DeleteCommand = " delete from Cases where Case_ID=" + id + "";  
        ds.Delete();  
    }   
}
```

Note, this is untested code. You should try to the what ASP.NET provides out of the box as [pistipanko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1139743/pistipanko) is suggesting.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't get it, what do you mean?